# Function call from aspx design time error "name does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net

I want to change the styles of certain elements on my page depending on the role of the logged in user.

To achieve this, I'm calling a function to execute some server code that does the evaluation and returns a string being the name of the style rule:

```
<li class="<%=CheckAllowed("admin"); %>">
```

In my code file I have the following:

```
public string CheckAllowed(string role)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsRole(role))
    {
        return "visible-menu-item";
    }
    else
    {
        return "hidden-menu-item";
    }
}
```

The function name in the markup is underlined red with the following error:

> The name 'CheckAllowed' does not exist in the current context.

Am I calling the function correctly? If not, how would this be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, your function is named CheckAddlowed, not CheckAllowed...

Try this syntax:

```
<% Response.Write(CheckAllowed("admin")); %>
```

Comment: No error anymore. I guess verbosity matters in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the use of `HttpContext.Current` in the method, it looks like it is located in a separate class than the page you are using it on. So provide the full namespace.

```
<%= Project1.ClassName.CheckAllowed("admin") %>
```

You probably need to make it a static class to work. But the intellisense should tell you that.

And it's `IsInRole` not `IsRole`